# Django 1.8, custom display link

Tags: django

I have created a custom link in the list display in django 1.8 but unfortunately its not showing as link but as a text.

```
list_display = ('site_name','view_link',)
#list_display_links = None

def view_link(self, obj):
    return "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (urlresolvers.reverse('admin:parkings_site_change', args=(obj.id,)),'View')
view_link.allow_tags = True
view_link.short_description = 'Action'
```

expected to see a hyperlink "View" instead of this text

```
<a href='/admin/parkings/site/1/'>View</a>.
```

Im not sure where is wrong, maybe someone can spot something here.

Comment: Do you define view_link in your Model?

Comment: no, do we need to do that. I cannot find reference about it

Comment: Documentation explain it like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Comment: I have solve this issue by using `return mark_safe("<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (urlresolvers.reverse('admin:parkings_site_change', args=(obj.id,)),'View'))`